# Visual Studio visualizer similar to Mole

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visualizer

Mole visualizer for WPF in Visual Studio is a great tool for debugging WPF apps. What I want to know is, is there a visualizer tool with Mole like functionality for general .Net debugging. I find the built in watch capabilities to be a little fidly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MOLE version 3.0, the tool has been able to work with all types of Visual Studio projects. [See here for more information about the tool and how to get the latest version.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/MoleForVisualStudioEdit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Mole 2010 works for all .net objects. I just used it for a winforms app and a WCF service and it works great.

They've got a free demo if you want to check it out http://www.molosoft.com

Cheers!